# Transfering between 2d coordinate systems where the x and y axes aren't perpendicular

Tags: math, vector, graphics

my question is more of a mathematical question in 2d computer graphics, but I figured that its more relevant here than the standard Stack overflow, if there's one dedicated especially to computer graphics by all means you can move this there.

Anyway my question is about transferring from 2 different 2d cartesian coordinate systems, where the coordinate systems are described as vectors that aren't necessarily perpendicular to each other.

[image]

As you can see in the diagram I provided, you have 3 local coordinate systems A,B and C defined by vectors: Ai,Aj,Bi,Bj,Ci,Cj.
I need to find a way to describe the point p in all the local coordinate systems and then find the transformation that takes a point from coordinate system C to B.

Now A is pretty easy, I can just move the origin back to 0,0 and rotate 90 degrees counter-clockwise and by multiplying these matrices I get the transformation that takes point P from the standard coordinate system to A.

Whats not clear to me is what to do with B and C since their axes aren't perpendicular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a transition between two coordinate systems, you have to calculate appropriate affine transform matrix. It is enough to have three non-collinear points in the first system and three corresponding points in the second system. For example, we can use triplet (5,6),(4,7)(2,7) for B, and triplet (4,3),(0,7),(0,1) for C system.

```
(x1 y1 1)       (X1 Y1 1)
(x2 y2 1) * M = (X2 Y2 1)
(x3 y3 1)       (X3 Y3 1)
```

M is affine matrix. To find M, we can left-multiply both sides by inverse of (x1...) matrix. [Resulting affine matrix](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=M%3Dinv+%7B%7B5%2C+6%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B4%2C+7%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B2%2C+7%2C+1%7D%7D+*+%7B%7B4%2C3%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C7%2C1%7D%7D) is:

```
     (0,  -3,  0)
M =  (-4, -5,  0)
     (28, 48,  1)
```

[Quick check](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N+%3D+%7B3%2C+7%2C+1%7D+*+%7B%7B0%2C+-3%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B-4%2C+-5%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B28%2C+48%2C+1%7D%7D)  for middle point between Bi, Bj ends gives `(3,7,1)*M=(0,4,1)`, middle point between Ci, Cj, as expected

Comment: Left top grid coordinate is (0,0). I selected B coordinate origin, Bi end, Bj end, and C coordinate origin, Ci end, Cj end. Note that I erroneously exchanged Ci and Cj - now corrected

Comment: Can I take the left bottom grid as (0,0) , would it matter? also I know affine transformation but the question was part of an assignment in computer graphics course and we still haven't reached affine transformation, what the book says is to use transformation matrices such as translation and rotation in order to align the axes with the standard axes, which is easy for A, but not clear regarding B and C. is there a way to do it with transformation matrices and not the method you used? Also how would you describe the coordinates of P with regards to B coordinate system? thanks

Comment: solve `Bi.X*u+Bj.X*v=1,Bi.Y*u+Bj.Y*v=1` to find (u,v) coordinates of P in B system. Learn `representation of vector in some basis`

Comment: thanks, you didn't answer my other question. can I take the bottom left as the origin instead of top left?

Comment: Yes, you can, it doesn't matter

Comment: Thanks, I'm still not sure how they wanted us to solve this only by using basic transformations and matrix multiplication.

Comment: And note that it is not enough to use only rotation and translation to align basis vectors here, you'll need also shear

Comment: ok so I guess they wanted us to do it with shear matrices, thats what I suspected at the begining. let me see if I understand your equation from above. if the origin of my coordinate system is left bottom then, Bj.X = 2 bj.Y = 1, Bi.X =4 and Bj.Y = 1? is that correct?

Comment: You wrote right values for end points, but not for vectors! Vector Bj=(-3, -1)

Comment: Oh sorry, so thats Bj.X = 2 - 5 = -3, Bj.Y = 1 - 2 = -1. Now I fully understand what you meant, thanks, I really appreciate it. I should really improve my linear algebra, its been a while since my Bsc.

Comment: ok I thought I had this clear but apparently I didn't. I looked at the formula you gave: Bi.X*u+Bj.X*v=1,Bi.Y*u+Bj.Y*v=1. I tried to take coordinate system A which is the easiest one, at first I didn't notice the =1 part of your formula, now I'm not sure where I need to input the coordinates for P in the standard coordinate system.

Comment: (1,-1) are coordinates of P in grid units relative to B origin

Comment: so if I were to calculate the same thing for A, that would be Ai.Xu + Aj.Xv = -1, Ai.Yu + Aj.Yv = -5 and then I will get that P's coordinates according to A system are (5,-1) ? am I correct?

Comment: Yes, P in A system is (5,-1). Just to make it clear, after you have wrote down everything in standard coordinates, so P(6,1), your system A origin Ao = (7,6) and your base vectors Ai = (0,-1), Aj = (1,0), then you solve `Ai.x * u + Aj.x * v + Ao.x = P.x` and `Ai.y * u + Aj.y * v + Ao.y = P.y` to get `P_A(u,v)` which is indeed `P_A(5,-1)`. Then repeat the same for systems B and C.

Comment: Thanks, I did it and I think it came out ok, I put these in matrices and used the inverse matrix, so P_B = (2,-1) and P_C(-1, 0.5). why did you specify the origin of A (7,6), it doesn't seem to take part in the calculations.